# Ant call to grails fails with "[exec] Application is pre-Grails 0.5, please run: grails upgrade"

Tags: grails, ant, groovy, groovy-console

I am facing a rather odd problem with our groovy build script. The whole project uses a helper groovy script that calls all other build scripts (maven and ant). One of the ant targets invoked by the groovy script calls, invokes through "exec" grails war:

```
    <exec executable="cmd" dir="${parentDir}/${grails.appname}">
        <arg value="/c"/>
        <arg path="${env.GRAILS_HOME}/bin/grails.bat"/>
        <arg value="war"/>
        <arg value="${grails.appname}-${app.version}.war"/>
    </exec>
```

The call of this block fails with:

```
     [exec] Application is pre-Grails 0.5, please run: grails upgrade
```

Any suggestions how to go around this problem?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: are you able to run 'grails war' correctly on the application directory? That error would indicate that something within your app structure got destroyed

Comment: Same exception if I run it from command line. After running the upgrade as suggested it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution to the problem, I don't know if this is the best way but it fixed  my problem. So in the same target as the "exec" block I added a new "exec" block to invoke the upgrade on the grails.bat. So far so good, calling this command without parameters will generate a confirmation question whether to proceed with the requested operation - in ant this will create an infinite loop. In order to avoid this I added the "-f" parameter. The whole exec block:

```
    <exec executable="cmd" dir="${parentDir}/${grails.appname}">
        <arg value="/c"/>
        <arg path="${env.GRAILS_HOME}/bin/grails.bat"/>
        <arg value="upgrade"/>
        <arg value="-force"/>
    </exec>
```

Hope this will help somebody.